# ReactJS - How can I call a function only AFTER a CSS animation has completed?

Tags: reactjs, css-animations

So I have a list of song request components. On click I'm trying to animate one of the song request components by sliding it off the screen, and then I want to call a function to remove that particular song request from my database.

`removeAnimation()` is called when I click to remove a song request. This successfully animates the song request component, however when I use the optional second parameter in `this.setState()` to execute `removeRequest()`, it executes before my animation is complete, causing my component to disappear long before the animation is done.

```
  removeRequest(request) {
    axios.delete(`/api/requests/${request.adminId}/${request.id}`)
    .then(() => {
      this.props.getRequests();
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.error(err);
    });
  },

  removeAnimation(request) {
    this.setState({ slide: true, requestToDelete: request }, this.removeRequest(request));
  }
```

I've messed around with using some of the component lifecycle update methods like `componentDidMount()` and `componentDidUpdate()` but I'm not really getting anywhere.

Comment: Do you use `ReactCSSTransitionGroup` for animation? if so then you can easy handle it directly on child component (song). What is the reason of handling animation within parent component?